# Changing file permission to execute

Tags: linux, command-line, file-permissions

My shell script runs from the command line, but fails in cronjob.

```
/bin/sh: asper.sh: Permission denied

-rw-r--r-- asper.sh
```

I guess the permission should look like '-rwxr-xr--'

How can I change the permission to be like that?

Comment: `chmod +x asper.sh`.  Also, this is not really a Stack Overflow question.  Maybe superuser?  Server fault?

Comment: chmod +x asper.sh will result in -rwxr-xr-x which will also work, but is not the permission setting asked for in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want permissions to look like -rwxr-xr--:

```
chmod 754 asper.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add the execute bit, it's as easy as:

```
chmod +x asper.sh
```